# Transform on Scroll - as smooth as on medium.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transform

i'm pretty sure a few of you guys know the website medium.com articles page.

For example, here: [Click](https://medium.com/@JanLosert/14-different-ways-of-product-design-3f349a19e613#.wug3ohavo)

There is a very "easy" effect on this page when you scroll down – opacity and transform changes. Not a big deal at first sight. I've implemented the same effect probably more then 10 times on websites already.

But if you take a closer look at it, you can see how absolutely perfect smooth this is. Seems like the text is perfectly gliding above the surface. (Im checking it on the latest Chrome)

I was keen if this is just imagination, and quickly built up the same thing to check this. So i came up with this code:

```
        var windowTop;
        var limit = 420;    

        function parallax(){

            parallaxElem.css({

                "opacity": (1 - (windowTop / limit)),
                "-webkit-transform":"translate3d(0," + (100 * (windowTop / limit)) + "px,0)",
                "-ms-transform":"translate3d(0," + (100 * (windowTop / limit)) + "px,0)",
                "transform":"translate3d(0," + (100 * (windowTop / limit)) + "px,0)"

            });

        }

        $(window).on('scroll', function(){

            windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();

            parallax();

        });
```

And it's by far not as smooth as the code on the Medium website.

Anyone any idea, what they are doing to get this super smooth scroll transform effect? I just can't find it out – their code is too complex/too compressed for me, to get any information out of it.

Thank's a lot for any answer in advance!

Regards
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest improvement is to go from this:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  parallax();
});
```

to:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  window.requestAnimationFrame(parallax);
});
```

Store windowTop inside of the parallax function. There's no point in making that an out of scope variable.

Additionally, although you don't have it in your sample code "parallaxElem" *should* be an out of scope variable, because you don't want to do a DOM search for the element on every scroll.

Comment: At first – thanks a lot, seems to be much more smooth right now! I have read the definition of window.requestAnimationFrame, but i'm not getting it since i am not animating anything in here. Could you give me a quick explanation why i should use it and when?

Comment: You are animating, just not in the way you think. What you're doing with css transform is still causing the browser to repaint. What happens in just doing the change in the scroll or a setInterval is that when your code triggers, the browser may not be ready to do a repaint. requestAnimationFrame tells the browser to try doing your change to the DOM when it is has time.